# Materials to unity

Tags: materials

I made a model with materials from blender assigned on it (using cycles render) and I tried to take the model to unity but the materials won't show up. I thought the materials were attached to the object or the blender file. It seems I'm was wrong. Do I have to use unity materials? Do I have to apply the material to the uv map and save the image so I can use it within unity?

Just if someone could explain me if it's preferable to always save it on the uv map for that kind of work or am doing something wrong and there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

Unity can't neither use the the materials definition from cycles nor Blender internal. So far I had no success assigning multiple materials in Unity to a single mesh.

When I need to, I split the mesh into child objects and assign appropriate shaders.

When all Blender materials have a texture it's way easier to create a combined texture that covers all used textures. A texture can be assigned to almost all Unity shaders (including bump and specular maps).

Related:

- [Joining different UVmaps from different objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32871/joining-different-uvmaps-from-different-objects/32895#32895)